# OpenOffice/Mozilla *.dic file format

Tags: dictionary, mozilla, openoffice.org

I would like use openoffice/mozilla dictionary at own aplication. I tried find dic file format documentation (it seems easy) but I have problem with this. If someone have this kind of documentation I will be grateful for information

Answer (score 6):

In the beginning there was MySpell and then there was the UTF-8 version, Hunspell...

Cutting the story short, basically there are two files: *.dic and *.aff.

The first one contains a list of correct words.
The second one has [affixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affixes).

I found a [link](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/fichiers_speciaux/hunspell) that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

According to my [first result](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=33297) on google it's a plain-text (UTF-8 encoded) file, which lists all the words in alphabetical order on separate lines (`\r\n` line ending) starting from line 2. Line 1 contains the number of words.

A short look into a random .dic file confirms that. Shouldn't be too complicated to find such things.

Comment: I think that it is not so easy, this is the begining of GB dictionary (from mozilla xpi file) it looks that some prefix are aded
46280

abaft
abbreviation/
M
abdicate/
DNGSn
Abelard/
M
abider/
M
Abidjan
ablaze
abloom
aboveground
abrader/
M
Abram/

Comment: I've seen them too, looks like gender information or something. I'm sure you've tried it anyway.